# Add or delete active class in for element

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I want to add or remove css class when an option of menu is selected but I have a problem, so my html:

```
 <ul class="nav" id="main-menu">
            <li>
                <a class="active" href="1.html"><i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-3x"></i>Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="2.html"><i class="fa fa-desktop fa-3x"></i>Add</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="3.html"><i class="fa fa-qrcode fa-3x"></i>View</a>
            </li>
</ul>
```

my css:

```
.active{
    background-color:#C90000!important;
 }
```

my jquery:

```
$('nav li a').on('click', function() {  
$('nav li a.active').removeClass('active');
$(this).addClass('active');    
});
```

Help me please guys

Comment: what is that *a problem*?

Comment: when I click the class active doesn't remove..status remains the same

Comment: Not sure what the problem is – can you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: Are you using `$(document).ready(function (){ /* your code here */})`, or putting your JavaScript/jQuery in a position that allows the DOM to be created before the JavaScript is executed?

Answer (score 1):

Use `.nav` instead of `nav` to refer to the UL element

```
$('.nav li a')
$('.nav li a.active')
```

Testable here: http://jsfiddle.net/c9j3u7af/

Answer (score 0):

Since "nav" is a class you must add a dot before it.

Your jQuery should be:

```
$('.nav li a').on('click', function() {  
$('.nav li a.active').removeClass('active');
$(this).addClass('active');    
});
```

Comment: I added but no result

Comment: You'll have to explain more what is not working, because the fiddles of both answers work.